# Get RSSI Value of Android Explicitly Paired Devices

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have paired my device to the Android phone explicitly, via an app. This device is a MI-Band 2, and it is paired using the MI-FIT app. I am currently connecting to bluetooth devices using this code:

```
String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            int rssi = intent.getShortExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_RSSI, Short.MIN_VALUE);
```

However, the problem is that if the MI-band is connected via the mi-fit app, I cannot get the RSSI value from the MI-Band.

Is it possible to get the RSSI value of explicitly paired devices in Android? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit: It seems like I can't get RSSI values of any connected devices. For example, if Android phone A is connected to Android Phone B, then I can't read the RSSI values when trying to read via the above code from Phone A.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure the bluetooth name of device to be connected, maybe you can try using [BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback.html) to get noticed when it's scanned. Or do you really need to tell scanned or connected apart?

```
BluetoothManager bleManager = (BluetoothManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
BluetoothAdapter bleAdapter = bleManager.getAdapter();
bleAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);// find match device
BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            if (device.getName() == null || !device.getName().equals("your bluetooth device name")) {
                return;
            }
            // here you can get rssi of specified bluetooth device if it's available.
            // and try to connect it programmatically.
            connect(device.getAddress());
        }
    };
```